# What is a word that could be used both for an ancestor and a descendant at the same time (excluding siblings, cousins etc)?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, my parents, my parents' parents, my children, my children's children etc. Everybody in my family tree vertically.

I need specifically person, and "both" ancestors and descendants; not one or the other, and not both in general including side relationships such as siblings or cousins.

Comment: TimLymington: Not exactly. That is much more general. I need specifically meaning "both".

Comment: I don't think you will get any more concise term than *ancestors and descendants.* You could say your personal DNA contributors and recipients.

Comment: By analogy with "lightcone", how about "kincone"?